# Transclude HTML in Apache Wicket component

Tags: wicket-6

I want to transclude html in a component, similar on how angularjs does with transclude:true (directives).

Suppose I have this html

```
<div wicket:id="myComponent> My content </div>
```

I want the component to write "My content" where I specify.
In MyComponent.html:

```
<wicket:panel>   
//Some other code
TRANSCLUDE HERE: "My content" should be here.
</wicket:panel>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand, derive WebMarkupContainder (higher components too) and implement OnComponentTagBody()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what org.apache.wicket.markup.html.border.Border component does.

The markup of a Border looks like:

```
<wicket:border>
  // some HTML with or without wicket:id here
 <wicket:body/>
  // some more HTML with or without wicket:id here
<wicket:border>
```

At the usage site you have:

```
<div wicket:id="myborder">
   // anything here will replace <wicket:body/> in the snippet above
</div>
```